# Parse.Query.each() chained promises

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code

I'm writing a `background job` function on `Parse.com` `CloudCode`. The `job` needs to call the same function (that includes a `Parse.Query.each()`call) several times with different parameters, and I want to chain these calls with promises. Here's what I have so far:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("threadAutoReminders", function(request, response) {

    processThreads(parameters1).then(function() {
        return processThreads(parameters2);
    }).then(function() {
        return processThreads(parameters3);
    }).then(function() {
        return processThreads(parameters4);
    }).then(function() {
        response.success("Success");
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
});
```

Below is the `processThreads()` function:

```
function processThreads(parameters) {

    var threadQuery = new Parse.Query("Thread");
    threadQuery... // set up query using parameters

    return threadQuery.each(function(thread) {
        console.log("Hello");
        // do something
    });
}
```

My questions are:

- Am I chaining function calls using promises correctly?
- What happens in `threadQuery.each()` returns zero results? Will the promise chain continue with execution? I'm asking because at the moment "Hello" never gets logged..

Comment: Does `each()` return a promise? What does its callback do?

Comment: `each()` returns nothing, it just updates an object and stores it in an array.

Comment: Is there anything asynchronous in `processThreads` at all?

Comment: Then there is no reason to use promises either. Just call the function multiple times, synchronously, without any `then` chaining.

Comment: How about the `each()` functions? I will have several of them running concurrently, right? (a) Is there no limitation on concurrent processes in Parse background job? (b) Is it OK for several threads to be writing to the same array at the same time?

Comment: Well you said they weren't asynchronous, so they shouldn't be running concurrently either.

Comment: Aside from the obvious `each()` call, which is asynchronous, there are no more asynchronous calls - sorry I didn't point that out. In case I _would_ need to use promises, is my chaining correct?

Comment: Yes, your `then` chaining is correct. Only if `each` is asynchronous, and does not return anything, you'll need to find a way to detect when it has finished its asynchronous execution, and then return a promise for that.

Comment: The value that returns `processThreads` will be passed to the next `then`. In this case, you passed `undefined` because `each`, as you have said, returns nothing. You can create a promise in `processThreads` then *reject* or `resolve` it and at lastly, after you `each`, return this promise.

Comment: @Pollin, would you mind creating an answer with sample code to illustrate your suggestion?

Comment: Artooras, is "do something" `doSomethingSynchronous() ` or `doSomethingAsynchronous() `?

Comment: "do something" is synchronous

Answer (score 2):

> Am I chaining function calls using promises correctly?

Yes.

> What happens in threadQuery.each() returns zero results? Will the promise chain continue with execution? I'm asking because at the moment "Hello" never gets logged.

I think I'm right in saying that, if "do something" is synchronous, then zero "Hello" messages can only happen if :

- an uncaught error occurs in "do something" before a would-be "Hello" is logged, or
- every stage gives no results (suspect your data, your query or your expectation).

You can immunise yourself against uncaught errors by catching them. As Parse promises are not throw-safe, you need to catch them manually :

```
function processThreads(parameters) {
    var threadQuery = new Parse.Query("Thread");
    threadQuery... // set up query using parameters
    return threadQuery.each(function(thread) {
        console.log("Hello");
        try {
            doSomething(); // synchronous
        } catch(e) {
            //do nothing
        }
    });
}
```

That should ensure that the iteration continues and that a fulfilled promise is returned.

Comment: The problem I see with this, based on my code logs, is that nothing inside the `each()` callback gets called if there are no threads found

Comment: Yes, highly likely. Eliminate the other possibility by running with no "doSomething", just `console.log("Hello");`.

Answer (score 1):

The following example shows as use promises inside your function using a web browser implementation.

```
function processThreads(parameters) {

    var promise = new Promise();
    var threadQuery = new Parse.Query("Thread");
    threadQuery... // set up query using parameters

    try {
        threadQuery.each(function(thread) {
            console.log("Hello");
            if (condition) {
                throw "Something was wrong with the thread with id " + thread.id;
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        promise.reject(e);

        return promise;
    }

    promise.resolve();

    return promise;
}
```

Implementations of promise:

> Web Browser https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
>
> jQuery https://api.jquery.com/promise/
>
> Angular https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q